# Access denied while using XAMPP on OS X Mavericks

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Does anyone know why I would be getting an Access Denied error using XAMPP on OS X?

When I go to `localhost/phpmyadmin` I get the message `#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

and when I go to just `localhost` I get

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is
>   either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

Is this a permissions issue? I added the password `root` to the username `root` in the phpmyadmin config file, but that didn't work and it wouldn't explain why I am getting the error on `localhost` as well. What IS working is the virtual host I created called `my.server`, but other than that, I seem to be locked out for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Is a MySQL error. That's saying that there was an attempt to connect to the MySQL server, and either the specified user account doesn't exist, or the passwords don't match. From another client that can connect, verify the user account exists

```
SELECT u.user, u.host, u.password
  FROM mysql.user
 WHERE u.user = 'root'
   AND u.host = 'localhost'
```

If the password column is empty, then there's no password on that account. If there's a '*688D...' value in there, you can compare the value of the hash of the password you're supplying...

```
SELECT PASSWORD('mysecretpassword')
```

Also, I'd recommend you create a DIFFERENT database user account (other than 'root'@'localhost', for use by your PHP scripts. (As one advantage, this will allow you to apply the security principle of "least privilege", granting only the privileges required.

---

The other error is saying that the webserver isn't configured to allow access to the URI you've specified, in the case of "`http://localhost/`", the webserver isn't configured to allow access to the ROOT of the webserver directory. (This is usually a really a good thing, in terms of security, not exposing the contents of this directory.)